# ASP.NET Core: getting url params not firing constructor

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

In one of my pages I am creating the link to the next page like this:

```
 <div class="joboffer" onclick="location.href='/Jobs/JobOverview?id=@elem.Id';" style="cursor: pointer;">
     <p>@elem.Title</p>
 </div>
```

This opens the correct page.

This page has a constructor which looks like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetid(string id)
{
    if (!_2_LogIn.IsLoggedIn)
    {
        await Response.WriteAsync("<script>alert('Nicht so schnell!!!')</script>");
        return BadRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        // gets the url params 
        return Page();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, even though the page is opened with the url `"?id=xxxxx"`, the constructor that is supposed to catch the params is never called.

Why is that?

Best,

J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, `OnGetId` method is not a constructor, it seems like a OnGet method in razor page.

For example, I have this method in my `Privacy` page:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetId(string id)
{
    if (!_2_LogIn.IsLoggedIn)
    {
        await Response.WriteAsync("<script>alert('Nicht so schnell!!!')</script>");
        return BadRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        // gets the url params 
        return Page();
    }
}
```

If I want to pass value to this method via route, I can use:

```
<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-page="/Privacy" asp-page-handler="Id" asp-route-id="xxx">Privacy</a>
```

Or

```
<div class="joboffer" onclick="location.href='/Privacy?id=xxx&handler=Id';" style="cursor: pointer;">
    Privacy
</div>
```

to pass value.

Comment: thank you! that did the trick! I was missing the handler part to the url